Drawbacks of image rectification for 3d reconstruction
When running 3d scene reconstruction algorithms using monocular camera systems you can choose to rectify each pair of images or do 3d reconstruction with unrectified pairs using epipolar geometry.
What are the drawbacks of image rectification?
